# Converting SQL SERVER Query to snowflake SQL -For calculating precision and recall for coded encounters

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hope you are doing well!.. An encounter is indicated by the combination of ctextid and vbillid ...A human codes the encounter and the entered set of codes by the human is represented in the agent entered codes column in input table (Column C).. From these set of codes we need to consider only the codes present in the match table and remove the ones not present in the match table from the agent entered codes column in input table thus creating a new column agent entered matching codes . .. The ML Predicted codes column indicates the set of codes that are automatically generated ...

Between the agent entered matching codes column and the ML predicted codes column we need to find the set of intersecting codes ...

After that the metrics precision and recall are calculated as the following :

Precision -( Number of codes in matching codes column)/ (Number of codes in the ML predicted code column)*100

A code is separated from the other by a comma..

Recall -( Number of codes in matching codes column)/ (Number of codes in the agent entered matching code column)*100

Please find below the DDL for the input table ,match table and the output table ..Can you please help me here..

```
Input table

create table ##input
(ctextid int,
vbillid int,
agententeredcodes varchar(100000),
MLpredictedcode varchar(100000))

insert into ##input values
('711','475','H6692,J309','J309, H6692'),
('811','130','I714,I2510,I77810,Z9862,E785,I119,Z955,I639','I2510'),
('9021','900','Z00129,E669,Z6853','Z00129, Z7189, Z713'),
('9234','890','E039,I10,E559,R7303,Z760,Z6829,Z79899,Z79890','I10, E039, E559, R7303')

Match table

create table ##match
(codelist varchar (10000)
)

insert into ##match values
('J309'),
('H6692'),
('I2510'),
('E785'),
('I119'),
('I639'),
('Z6853'),
('I10'),
('E039'),
('E559'),
('Z79899'),
('R7303'),
('Z760'),
('Z6829')

##output

create table ##output
(ctextid int,
vbillid int,
agententeredcodes varchar(100000),
agententeredmatchingcodes varchar (100000),
MLpredictedcodes varchar(100000),
matchingcodes varchar(100000),
precision int,
recall int
)

insert into ##output values
('711','475','H6692,J309','H6692,J309','J309, H6692','J309, H6692','100','100'),
('811','130','I714,I2510,I77810,Z9862,E785,I119,Z955,I639','I2510,E785,I119,I639','I2510','I2510','100','25'),
('9021','900','Z00129,E669,Z6853','Z00129,E669','Z00129, Z7189, Z713','Z00129','33.3333333333333','50'),
('9234','890','E039,I10,E559,R7303,Z760,Z6829,Z79899,Z79890','I10,E039,E559,Z79899,R7303,Z760,Z6829','I10, E039, E559, R7303','I10, E039, E559, R7303','100','50')
```

For the above logic I have the following SQL server version of the code which I need to convert to snowflake SQL..Can you please help me here..

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
 (SELECT ctextid,vbillid ,codelist AS agententeredmatchingcodes,COUNT(1)OVER(PARTITION BY ctextid,vbillid)AS AgentMatchCount
   FROM ##input CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(agententeredcodes,',') S
                LEFT JOIN ##match M ON LTRIM(S.VALUE)=M.codelist
   WHERE codelist IS NOT NULL
 ),CTE2 AS (
  SELECT ctextid,vbillid ,STRING_AGG(matchingcodes,',') matchingcodes,MAX(MatchCount) MatchCount FROM
  (SELECT I.ctextid,I.vbillid ,C.agententeredmatchingcodes AS matchingcodes,COUNT(1)OVER(PARTITION BY I.ctextid,I.vbillid)AS MatchCount
   FROM ##input I CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(MLpredictedcode,',')S
                  LEFT JOIN CTE1 C ON I.ctextid=C.ctextid AND I.vbillid=C.vbillid AND LTRIM(S.VALUE)=C.agententeredmatchingcodes
   WHERE agententeredmatchingcodes IS NOT NULL)A
  GROUP BY ctextid,vbillid
 ),CTE3 AS
 (SELECT ctextid,vbillid,STRING_AGG(VALUE,',') MLpredictedcode,MAX(MLCount) MLCount
  FROM (SELECT ctextid,vbillid,VALUE,COUNT(1)OVER(PARTITION BY ctextid,vbillid)AS MLCount
        FROM ##input CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(MLpredictedcode,','))A
  GROUP BY ctextid,vbillid
 )
 SELECT I.ctextid,I.vbillid,agententeredcodes,STRING_AGG(C1.agententeredmatchingcodes,',')agententeredmatchingcodes,C3.MLpredictedcode,C2.matchingcodes,
        CONVERT(decimal(18, 0),MatchCount*1.0/MLCount*100)AS precision,CONVERT(decimal(18, 0),MatchCount*1.0/MAX(C1.AgentMatchCount)*100)AS recall 
 FROM ##input I LEFT JOIN CTE1 C1 ON I.ctextid=C1.ctextid AND I.vbillid=C1.vbillid
                LEFT JOIN CTE2 C2 ON I.ctextid=C2.ctextid AND I.vbillid=C2.vbillid
                LEFT JOIN CTE3 C3 ON I.ctextid=C3.ctextid AND I.vbillid=C3.vbillid
 GROUP BY I.ctextid,I.vbillid,agententeredcodes,C3.MLpredictedcode,C2.matchingcodes,C2.MatchCount,C3.MLCount
```

Should cross apply be replaced with inner join ,STRING_AGG with listagg and string_split with split_part..But still I am getting errors

```
with expand_agententeredcodes as (
    select ctextid, vbillid, trim(column_value) agententeredcodes
    from input,
      xmltable(('"'
      || REPLACE(agententeredcodes, ',', '","')
      || '"'))
),
agententeredmatchingcodes as (
    select ctextid, vbillid, agententeredcodes
     from expand_agententeredcodes  a
     join match                     m on m.codelist = a.agententeredcodes
),
expand_mlpredictedcodes as (
    select ctextid, vbillid, trim(column_value) mlpredictedcode
    from input,
      xmltable(('"'
      || REPLACE(mlpredictedcode, ',', '","')
      || '"'))
),
number_matching_rows as (
    select a.ctextid, a.vbillid, count(*) cnt
    from  agententeredmatchingcodes a   
    join  expand_mlpredictedcodes ml
        on ml.mlpredictedcode = a.agententeredcodes
        and  ml.ctextid = a.ctextid     
        and  ml.vbillid = a.vbillid     
    group by a.ctextid, a.vbillid
)

 
 
select  i.ctextid, i.vbillid, i.agententeredcodes, i.mlpredictedcode,
        '---->' calc_precision,
        cnt, 1+REGEXP_COUNT(i.agententeredcodes, ',') cprec,
        100 * (cnt / (1+REGEXP_COUNT(i.agententeredcodes, ','))) precision,
 
        '---->' calc_recall,
        cnt, 1+REGEXP_COUNT(i.mlpredictedcode, ',') crec,
        100 * (cnt / (1+REGEXP_COUNT(i.mlpredictedcode, ','))) recall
from input                  i
join number_matching_rows  eq on     eq.ctextid = i.ctextid
                                 and eq.vbillid = i.vbillid
```

Comment: Any help on this thread would be appreciated!

Comment: Please update your question with the errors you are seeing with the SQL you’ve written. If you want an opinion on why your question hasn’t received any responses it is because it initially reads like you are asking someone to re-write code for you (which is unlikely to happen) and your question is far too long, especially as most of it is irrelevant. Provide the code you’ve written, enough sample data to demonstrate the problem, the result you want to achieve with the data and any relevant information - such as errors you see when you run your code